# Rust installation issue in ubuntu-gnome 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, ssl, curl, rust

I am having trouble installing Rust on my ubuntu-gnome 16.04.2. I followed the basic installation mentioned on the [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html) website. I am attaching the command output for perusal

```
$ curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
info: downloading installer

Welcome to Rust!

This will download and install the official compiler for the Rust programming 
language, and its package manager, Cargo.

It will add the cargo, rustc, rustup and other commands to Cargo's bin 
directory, located at:

  /home/pearlstud/.cargo/bin

This path will then be added to your PATH environment variable by modifying the
profile file located at:

  /home/pearlstud/.profile

You can uninstall at any time with rustup self uninstall and these changes will
be reverted.

Current installation options:

   default host triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     default toolchain: stable
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
1

info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
error: could not download file from 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256' to '/home/pearlstud/.rustup/tmp/323e8vx3qfke7r7w_file'
info: caused by: error during download
info: caused by: [35] SSL connect error (error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol)
```

Comment: Have you resolved it yet?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. If you've managed to resolve it, do post the solution as an answer to your question.

Comment: I am sorry but I think I changed the system. I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

googling your ssl error returned this, I would try these solutions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166950/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-how-do-i-fix-my-ssl-cert

maybe you messed with your ssl?